# Copying Salesforce App and data into development environment

Tags: salesforce

The Theatre department in the University I work for is currently using Salesforce (PatronManager app) to sell tickets. My team is currently looking to leverage the Salesforce API to display a comprehensive list of performances by date on our mobile application and, possibly later on, provide users the ability to purchase tickets directly through the app.

Since we obviously don't want to mess around with the data on our live implementation, I set up a development account on Salesforce. Is there a simple way to "dump" the Custom Object schema as well as the data into a file that I can easily import into an new app on the development account (similar to what I would do with a traditional database), or even copy the entire app, along with its data to development.

I apologize in advance for this newbie question. I just started using Salesforce this week, and most of my time with it has been playing with the API.

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the edition used, the department might have a sandbox available to them — this is basically a clone of the live environment which you can use for development, and if it's a full-copy sandbox it will also include data.

If you want to do it via your development org, I'd suggest deploying the objects from the production Org using Eclipse or changesets, to your dev org. Then you can use dataloader or an ETL tool to take a copy of the data, though if you have lookups etc. then you'll need to do some massaging in excel before using dataloader.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you want to do is create the sandbox. You can do a Full-Sandbox which can be refreshed (schema and data) every 30 days. You can also create developer/config only sandbox which copies over the schema from production along with a few other standard object's data.

The key here is that you want to copy data from production to a sandbox. If this is right, then I'd first check to see if a Full-Sandbox is sufficent. Now the two hinderances of a Full-Sandbox is that it can only be refereshed every 30 days and that its expensive.

The other alternative is to use a developer or (prefereably) a config only sandbox. If you decide to use these, then copying the data is done using an ETL tool although setting it up is time consuming and can get hairy.

I developed an app called sfxorgdata (www.sfapex.com) which copies data across from prod-full/dev/config and sandbox-sandbox. You dont have to worry about relationships, dependencies, external ids, validation rules, data size because this app takes care of that.

Anyways, without turning this into a marketing pitch, check it out and let me know if its what you're looking to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate a Developer Sandbox or Configuration Sandbox (in your live instance, go to setup - data management - sandboxes) which will be a copy of you live Schema but without data.

The transfer of data can also be done, for free, with open-source ETL tools, for example [TalenD](http://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio)

I've just written a lengthy step-by-step example of how to do this with TalenD on my blog:

[Copying data to Salesforce Sandboxes using TalenD](http://www.codeulike.com/2014/02/copying-data-to-salesforce-sandboxes.html)

This covers all the details, including how to use External IDs to make sure relationships between objects are preserved as you copy the data from Source to Target.